# Extracting only the module and the libraries from the AMD ATI proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, ati, fglrx

I need to use this drivers in a Linux based system that is highly customized and so I'd like to know if there is a way of having this pieces just ready to be manually installed and/or used.

In other terms I need the *.so libraries and the kernel module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download the [ATI binary driver for linux,](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

If you do `./ati-XX.run --help` you could see a lot of options, IIRC, there's an `--extract` option that will extract everything inside to a folder, which contains:

```
Kernel module (fglrx) source code
fglrx opengl library (binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to visit the [AMD Driver Download site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) and follow the instructions there to determine which driver you need.

Once you have downloaded it, their "installer" will give you the rest of what you need.  Keep in mind, you will need to make sure you have the kernel headers installed or available for their installer to work.